# recyclerview click goto new page android page info.xml and send Product Title

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

recyclerview click goto new page android page info.xml and send Product Title
I am trying to create an e-commerce app
How can I add onclick in RecyclerView list open product info page like new Activity, I'd like also to send proct Title and ID  in product info page,

```
public class adepter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adepter.viewholder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Product> productList;

    public adepter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, parent, false);
        return new viewholder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder holder, int position) {
        Product product = productList.get(position);
                //loading the image
                Glide.with(mCtx)
                        .load(product.getImage())
                        .into(holder.imageView);
                holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
                holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(product.getShortdesc());
                holder.textViewtype.setText(String.valueOf(product.getType()));
                holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }


    public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc, textViewtype, textViewPrice;
        ImageView imageView;
            public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            textViewShortDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShortDesc);
            textViewtype = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);
            textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
             }
     }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Intents to pass values as below :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder holder, int position) {
    Product product = productList.get(position);
            //loading the image
            Glide.with(mCtx)
                    .load(product.getImage())
                    .into(holder.imageView);
            holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
            holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(product.getShortdesc());

    holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
    final Product p=product ;
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent=new Intent(mCtx,InfoPage.class);
    intent.putExtra("prod_id",p.getID());
    intent.putExtra("prod_title",p.getTitle());
    startActivity(intent);

}});

}
```

Product Info Page Ativity seems like :

```
public class InfoPage extends AppCompatActivity
{
    WebView webview;
    String product_id,product_tile;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.product_info_xml);
      product_id=getIntent().getStringExtra("prod_id");
      product_tile=getIntent().getStringExtra("prod_title");
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle(product_tile);
      webview=findViewbyID(R.id.myWebView);
      webview.loadUrl("http://www.YourProductUrl.com");
    }
}
```

product_info_xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <WebViewView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i need only tital.setText(product_tile); but its not working

Comment: ```
        TextView tital = findViewById(R.id.tital);
   
        product_id=getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        product_tile=getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    tital.setText(product_tile);
    
    Toast.makeText(this, product_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();```    and  ``` Intent intent=new Intent(mCtx, product_info.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",product.getId());
                intent.putExtra("title",product.getTitle());
                mCtx.startActivity(intent);```

Comment: `
public class product_info extends AppCompatActivity {

    String product_id,product_tile;
  TextView id, tital;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_info);


        TextView tital = findViewById(R.id.tital);

        product_id=getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        product_tile=getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    tital.setText(product_tile);

    Toast.makeText(this, product_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
` @Aamir Shahzad

Comment: tital.setText(product_tile);  whats went wrong here?

Comment: Please note it's not a good idea to put OnClickListener in onBindViewHolder, make inner class to do the click listener.

Comment: @JimaleAbdi hi sir where I put on click listener please give me a code

Comment: Follow [this](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/) and let me know if difficult for you

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreateViewHolder add the `onClickListener` to your itemView's relevant view

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, parent, false);
    viewholder vh = new viewholder(v);
    vh.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
          Product product = productList.get(vh.getAdapterPosition());
          //do the page opening here

       }
    });
    return vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on simple and easy way

1. Define layout for your list item and set click listener on it.
2. Use intent to send data from recycler to your activity.

   public class adepter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

   ```
       private Context mCtx;
       private List<Product> productList;

       public adepter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
           this.mCtx = mCtx;
           this.productList = productList;
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
       viewType) {
           LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
           View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, parent, false);
           return new viewholder(v);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder holder, int 
       position) {
           Product product = productList.get(position);
                   //loading the image
                   Glide.with(mCtx)
                           .load(product.getImage())
                           .into(holder.imageView);
                   holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
                   holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(product.getShortdesc());


           holder.textViewtype.setText(String.valueOf(product.getType()));

           holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
           holder.ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent=new Intent(yourContext,YourActivity.class);
                   intent..putExtra("title",product.getTitle);
                   context.startActivity(intent);

               }
           });
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return productList.size();
       }


       public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
           TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc, textViewtype, 
           textViewPrice;
           ImageView imageView;
           LinearLayout ll;

               public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
               textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
               textViewShortDesc = 
              itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShortDesc);
               textViewtype = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);
               textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
               imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
               ll=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll);// your layout
                }
        }


   }
   ```